# How do I properly input my own test cases in my own IDE for problems in leetcode.com?

Tags: python

I am new to LeetCode.com and I encountered my first problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/solution/).

A default code or template is provided for the problem above, but as I have observed in other people's solutions, they simplified it to this:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    # ... code here ...
    return [...]
```

I do not use the editor provided by LeetCode. I use my own IDE (VSCode) instead.
Whenever I try to create my own inputs to test my code, I add the following lines:

```
x = Solution.twoSum("",[1, 7, 2], 9)
print(x)
```

The **""** is assigned to the ***self*** argument, the following *list* is for ***nums***, and the **9** is for **target**.

Initially, I didn't have the **""**:

```
    def twoSum([1, 7, 2], 9)
```

So I get ***TypeError: twoSum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target'***

Is this how people really test their codes, by assigning a random object (in my case, it's **""**) to the ***self*** argument?
Or is there another way that is cleaner?

I am familiar with basics of OOP, so I thought maybe there's supposed to be a ***def __init__*** to initialize something. However, other people's solutions don't make use of this.

Comment: You will need to refactor your code. Here's a trick: I usually keep the function parameter names same and then copy everything in the function and paste it in the leetcode function ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a template that I use for [python](/questions/tagged/python):

```
from typing import List
import collections
import itertools
import functools
import math
import string
import random
import bisect
import re
import operator
import heapq
import queue

from queue import PriorityQueue
from itertools import combinations, permutations
from functools import lru_cache
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import deque
from collections import Counter




print(Solution().())
```

For twoSum, it would be:

```
from typing import List
import collections
import itertools
import functools
import math
import string
import random
import bisect
import re
import operator
import heapq
import queue

from queue import PriorityQueue
from itertools import combinations, permutations
from functools import lru_cache
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import deque
from collections import Counter


class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        index_map = {}
        for index, num in enumerate(nums):
            if target - num in index_map:
                return index_map[target - num], index
            index_map[num] = index


print(Solution().twoSum(nums=[2, 7, 11, 15], target=9))
print(Solution().twoSum(nums=[2, 7, 11, 15], target=18))
print(Solution().twoSum(nums=[2, 7, 11, 15], target=22))
```

#### Output

```
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, efficient algorithms with a variety of languages, and time/space complexity analysis in there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "change" the code accordingly. Take the following example:

Consider that the `leetcode` DSL is

```
Class Solution:
    def func(self, arg1, arg2):
```

How I would code this (in VScode/ed/ex/vi/vim/gedit/...) is as follows:

```
def func(arg1, arg2):    # notice that arg1 and arg2 also have same names
   <my stupid code> (Call this function and pass it input as requested)
```

And then, while submitting:

I simply copy paste `<my stupid code>` under the given function

---

In your case, this is what I would do:

My function in my favourite editor (ed)

```
def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    <my logic here (which usually does not work :P)>
```

Copy paste the `<my logic here (which usually does not work :P)>` stuff as it is
in the solution

---

And for printing, I would simply use the custom checker...

Answer (score 1):

I developed a script, so that you can write your code in a local file, test it with one operation, and submit it more easily.
You can get the whole project and explanation from [my repository](https://github.com/flowingwings/leetcode-localtest). Here I give a brief introduction.
The script is as following:

```py
import os
import answer

try:
    testDataPath = os.environ.get('TestDataPath')
    f = open(testDataPath)
    args = f.readlines()
    newArgs = []
    for arg in args:
        arg = arg.strip().replace('\"', '')
        # Handle quotation marks and carriage returns.
        newArgs.append(arg)
    args = newArgs
    funcName = dir(answer.Solution)[-1]
    if len(args) == 1:
        print(getattr(answer.Solution, funcName)('', args[0]))
    elif len(args) == 2:
        print(getattr(answer.Solution, funcName)('', args[0], args[1]))
    elif len(args) == 3:
        print(getattr(answer.Solution, funcName)('', args[0], args[1], args[2]))
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

To use this, you need to edit the run configuration:

```xml
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="LeetCodeTest" type="PythonConfigurationType" factoryName="Python">
    <module name="leetcode-localtest" />
    <option name="INTERPRETER_OPTIONS" value="" />
    <option name="PARENT_ENVS" value="true" />
    <envs>
      <env name="PYTHONUNBUFFERED" value="1" />
      <env name="TestDataPath" value="D:\read.txt" />
    </envs>
    <option name="SDK_HOME" value="C:\Users\62302\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" />
    <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
    <option name="IS_MODULE_SDK" value="false" />
    <option name="ADD_CONTENT_ROOTS" value="true" />
    <option name="ADD_SOURCE_ROOTS" value="true" />
    <EXTENSION ID="PythonCoverageRunConfigurationExtension" runner="coverage.py" />
    <option name="SCRIPT_NAME" value="C:\Users\62302\PycharmProjects\leetcode-localtest\lc-script.py" />
    <option name="PARAMETERS" value="" />
    <option name="SHOW_COMMAND_LINE" value="false" />
    <option name="EMULATE_TERMINAL" value="false" />
    <option name="MODULE_MODE" value="false" />
    <option name="REDIRECT_INPUT" value="false" />
    <option name="INPUT_FILE" value="" />
    <method v="2" />
  </configuration>
</component>
```

The procedure is as follows: Create `answer.py` in the same project; copy the template that LeetCode gives and paste it in `answer.py`; copy the input sample to your local file directly; write, test and debug your code locally; copy and paste it directly to submit it on LeetCode.

This script is very limited, but I think it has potential to become a elegant solution. Any suggestion and correction will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

These are the ways I did in VS code or Jupyter Notebook.

- 1

```py
class Solution(object):
    def two_sum(self, nums, target):
        result_idx = []
        for idx1 in range(0, len(nums)):
            for idx2 in range(1, len(nums)):
                if nums[idx1] + nums[idx2] == target:
                    result_idx.append(idx1)
                    result_idx.append(idx2)
                    break
        return result_idx
obj = Solution()
print (obj.two_sum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))
```

- 2

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, nums, target):
        self.nums = nums
        self.target = target
    
    def two_sum(self):
        result_idx = []
        for idx1 in range(0, len(self.nums)):
            for idx2 in range(1, len(self.nums)):
                if self.nums[idx1] + self.nums[idx2] == self.target:
                    result_idx.append(idx1)
                    result_idx.append(idx2)
                    break
        return result_idx

obj = Solution([2, 7, 11, 15], 9)
print("The result is:", obj.two_sum())
```

- 3

```py
class Solution:
    @staticmethod
    def two_sum(nums, target):
        result_idx = []
        for idx1 in range(0, len(nums)):
            for idx2 in range(1, len(nums)):
                if nums[idx1] + nums[idx2] == target:
                    result_idx.append(idx1)
                    result_idx.append(idx2)
                    break
        return result_idx

print("The result is:", Solution.two_sum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))
```